# Forcing an image into a fixed div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get an image to be scaled to the size of a table (unfortunately I need to keep the table) where the table is the same size as the div.  Looking at the link below, the picture on the way right is what I expect. However, in the bottom picture, the image is not staying in its 100% sized table.  Why doesn't the height get shrunk?

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/139980/image%20size%20experiment/index.html

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the dimensions of the container, why don't you just apply them to the image directly? What could possibly be the purpose for wanting to use the container to manage the size of the image instead of managing it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Apply height and width directly since you know the tables size.

```
<img src="imageName.png" width="20" height="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

try overflow hidden to div

> overflow:hidden

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It simply hides the image instead of scaling it down...

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have to say I never noticed this behavior before.  I have figured out a solution to your problem using Javascript.  The only way I was able to do it with CSS is if I specified the same Height and Width to the image as the DIV.

Therefore, the javascript sets the same Height and Width as the parenting DIV of the image element.  Hopefully this will be a viable solution for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function autoSize(i) 
{
    i.style.height = i.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height;
    i.style.width = i.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 400; height: 100;top: 200; left: 10;background-color: #CCCCCC">
    <table width=100% height=100%><tr><td align=center valign=middle>
        <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png" onload="autoSize(this)">
    </td></tr></table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is probably a better way of getting the parentNode, but I'll let you figure it out  :)

Comment: Heh, you've got to be kidding right. I only wish I could downvote more than once. I recommend reading about DOM methods sometime.